# How to temporarily disable code analysis locally?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, code-analysis

Here, we run a set of Visual Studio 2008's CA rules both locally and on the build server.  In order to check in, our CA rules must match the servers policy.  However, I work on a large solution with several projects.  Building the project in release mode takes a long time with the CA rules enabled, but this is necessary when creating or editing unit tests.  This makes working with unit tests a painful task.  What I'd like to do is to have a quick way (quicker than going through all projects to disable CA) to disable the CA rules during development, and then re-enable them on before checking in.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually create a "Debug No FxCop" build configuration at the solution level for this, with the only difference between the within-project configurations being the RunCodeAnalysis property that Graham has already mentioned.  Using a build configuration for this will allow you to avoid reloading your solution when you want to switch between CA and non-CA modes.

Answer (score 4):

The project file (*.csproj for C#) contains an element that controls if Code Analysis will be run - `<RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>`. (You can see this by opening the project file in a text editor, or Unloading the project in Visual Studio and then selecting Edit.)

You could write a script (e.g. using PowerShell) that would iterate through all of the project files, select the above element with an XPath, and toggle the value of it (i.e. `true` to `false` and vice-versa).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165271/) could be of use.

Comment: If you want to write a script (well a console application) have a look at the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558422/disable-code-analysis-at-solution-level-in-microsoft-visual-stdio-2012/16531391#16531391