# Is it possible to throttle Intellisense CPU use?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

My dev machine is absolutely crawling - programs frequently non-responsive, etc. It turns out VS2019 is maxing out my CPU (80-100%) for minutes at a time even when I'm not using it, and I've identified "Background Tasks" as the culprit, namely Intellisense. This is not simply when loading a solution, but hours later.

Is it possible to control how much CPU resource it is allowed to use? I don't want to turn it off (not sure if it's possible) but are there any settings because it is making my machine almost unusable.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52649461/10871073) (and links therein) help? Seems like it's the same thing.

Comment: @AdrianMole it seems related as another type of background task but I am not sure it's the same. I would _hope_ intellisense had some dedicated settings though

Comment: Any hopes and aspirations about IntelliSense being in any way intelligent are likely to end in tears.

Comment: There is no option to control the CPU resource that it allowed to use in Visual Studio. Also, IntelliSense has fewer settings in Visual Studio. You can close the auto completion feature temporarily to confirm that whether this issue is caused by IntelliSense. From VS > Tools > Options > Text Editor > language(for example C#) > IntelliSense > Completion and uncheck `Show completion list after a character is typed`…(remember to reboot your machine after changing the settings).

Comment: If it is caused by IntelliSense, I’m afraid there is no more effective ways to reduce the usage of CPU. You can report this issue to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem)(VS Product Team). If this isn’t caused by IntelliSense, then you may need to consider the installed extensions, some changed settings by yourself and disable them or [reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2019#reset-settings) them to see if this works.

Comment: BTW, update VS to the latest version may work.

Comment: thanks @TianyuSun-MSFT in my case it is background tasks when I'm not even doing anything. I have no extensions I think it's just building the model but being too aggressive with CPU use.

Comment: @Mr.Boy, I have submitted a feature request on Developer Community, here is the [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2019-frequently-non-responsive-is-it/1485156?space=8&entry=myfeedback), you can follow up that thread and provide more information there. Hope VS Product Team will help to add the related features in VS.